# Use VBA to build excel worksheet from text data

Tags: excel, spc, vba

We have some SPC software that will export data in the format below, We need to clean it and import it into excel, knowing that the measurements and the number of items being measured will change.

```
": Height__0.0:"
"NOM (LSL, USL) = 8.8428 (8.7828, 8.9028)"
"Subgroup"  5   
"Status"    "OS"    
"X" 8.8394  
"R" 0.1547  
"s" 0.0273  
"S1"    8.8445  
"S2"    8.8493  
"S3"    8.8450  
"S4"    8.8465  
"S5"    8.8483  
"S6"    8.8443  
"S7"    8.8315  
"S8"    8.8322  
"Inspector" "kh"    
"Machine"   "a12"   
"Sequence"  1-30    
"Station"   71445091    
"Material"  " " 
"Date/Time" " " 
"Time"  "10:23:02"  
"Date"  "03/18/2015"    

": Bead__45.0:"
"NOM (LSL, USL) = 0.8970 (0.8890, 0.9050)"
"Subgroup"  5   
"Status"    ""  
"X" 0.9013  
"R" 0.0050  
"s" 0.0012  
"S1"    0.9011  
"S2"    0.9005  
"S3"    0.8991  
"S4"    0.9014  
"S5"    0.9011  
"S6"    0.9017  
"S7"    0.9022  
"S8"    0.9019  
"Inspector" "kh"    
"Machine"   "a12"   
"Sequence"  1-30    
"Station"   71445091    
"Material"  " " 
"Date/Time" " " 
"Time"  "10:23:02"  
"Date"  "03/18/2015"
```

I need to build this data into an excel worksheet as so

```
Height__0.0     Bead__45.0
NOM 8.8428      NOM 0.8970
LSL 8.7828      LSL 0.8890
USL 8.9028      USL 0.9050
8.8445          0.9011
8.8493          0.9005
8.845           0.8991
8.8465          0.9014
```

etc...   Any advice where to start?

Comment: the original file will always have the same suffixes and format? same number of lines and the same spaces before the data you want?

Comment: i mean it will always have X than R than S and so on untill S8?

Comment: Yes those will always be there

Comment: the data appears ti be sequential, its a set so look for **":** and start the fetching the values what needs ti be extracted, **and** put 1 more data set and the output as well

Comment: SPC-Light and we produce some reports with excel, but eventually get it into Mini-Tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if it's always in this exac format this code can produce the table you want, you must paste the original code on the A column and run the macro, it will create the table on the B and C column:

```
Sub test()

Dim c1           As Integer
Dim c2           As Integer

c1 = 0
c2 = 0

Do While c1 < 25

Cells(1, 2 + c2) = Mid(Cells(1 + c1, 1), 4, WorksheetFunction.Search(":", Range("A1"), 3) - 4)
Cells(2, 2 + c2) = "NOM " & Mid(Cells(2 + c1, 1), 19, 6)
Cells(3, 2 + c2) = "LSL " & Mid(Cells(2 + c1, 1), 27, 6)
Cells(4, 2 + c2) = "USL " & Mid(Cells(2 + c1, 1), 35, 6)
For i = 5 To 8
Cells(i, 2 + c2) = Mid(Cells(i + 3 + c1, 1), 9, 6)
Cells(i, 2 + c2).NumberFormat = "0.0000"
Next

c2 = c2 + 1
c1 = c1 + 24

Loop

End Sub
```

If you'd like to use the last numbers with "." as decimal separator just place this line

```
Cells(i, 2 + c2) = "'" & Mid(Cells(i + 3 + c1, 1), 9, 6)
```

in the place of this 2

```
Cells(i, 2 + c2) = Mid(Cells(i + 3 + c1, 1), 9, 6)
Cells(i, 2 + c2).NumberFormat = "0.0000"
```

Comment: Thank you, When I tried to run it. I recieved `Unable to get Search property of WroksheetFunction class`

Comment: you've copied this exac code? i've just created a new workbook and tested it and i worked

Comment: try to copy the original text from you question and place it on the A column

Comment: Ok I am sorry, It does work.  How can I modify it to handle more "Sample" or "Measurements?

Comment: @WilliamKilgore can you give a example of what you want? because like i said this one works to do the exac example you gave me

Comment: @WilliamKilgore if you want the code to get all S from 1 to 8 and not just 1 to 4 just change the "for" interval, it's from 5 to 8, so if you want from 1 to 5 for example put it from 5 to 9 and so on

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, The amount of "S" may change from report to report, also the amount of measurements "height" "width" FtoB"  etc...